# Swagger UI documentation not opening for my spring boot 3 project with springdoc-openapi-ui dependency

Tags: spring-security, swagger-ui

I have a problem about opening swagger ui in my Spring Boot project.
I am able to hit my API from postman, only issue in accessing swagger ui documentation for my API. I am using spring doc open api dependency to configure swagger for my APIs.
I could see below logs while trying to access the swagger URL http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html. And the error in browser whitelabel error page.

```
2023-05-02T11:21:32.078+05:30 TRACE 18204 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@60743cdb, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@c02670f, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@2accaec2, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@1da1380b, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@5a1f778, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@654e6a90, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@83bb0f, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@40709f9, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@71179b6f, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@6418e39e, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@5f366587]] (1/1)
2023-05-02T11:21:32.078+05:30 DEBUG 18204 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /swagger-ui.html
2023-05-02T11:21:32.078+05:30 TRACE 18204 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/11)
2023-05-02T11:21:32.078+05:30 TRACE 18204 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/11)
2023-05-02T11:21:32.078+05:30 TRACE 18204 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderFilter (3/11)
2023-05-02T11:21:32.078+05:30 TRACE 18204 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/11)
2023-05-02T11:21:32.079+05:30 TRACE 18204 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking CsrfFilter (5/11)
2023-05-02T11:21:32.079+05:30 TRACE 18204 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter         : Did not protect against CSRF since request did not match CsrfNotRequired [TRACE, HEAD, GET, OPTIONS]
2023-05-02T11:21:32.079+05:30 TRACE 18204 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking LogoutFilter (6/11)
2023-05-02T11:21:32.079+05:30 TRACE 18204 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            : Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
2023-05-02T11:21:32.079+05:30 TRACE 18204 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking RequestCacheAwareFilter (7/11)
2023-05-02T11:21:32.079+05:30 TRACE 18204 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : matchingRequestParameterName is required for getMatchingRequest to lookup a value, but not provided
2023-05-02T11:21:32.079+05:30 TRACE 18204 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (8/11)
2023-05-02T11:21:32.079+05:30 TRACE 18204 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (9/11)
2023-05-02T11:21:32.079+05:30 TRACE 18204 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (10/11)
2023-05-02T11:21:32.079+05:30 TRACE 18204 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AuthorizationFilter (11/11)
2023-05-02T11:21:32.079+05:30 TRACE 18204 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Authorizing SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@15bea89d]
2023-05-02T11:21:32.080+05:30 TRACE 18204 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Checking authorization on SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@15bea89d] using org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizeHttpRequestsConfigurer$$Lambda$701/0x0000000801010c68@5afc8a57
2023-05-02T11:21:32.080+05:30 DEBUG 18204 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /swagger-ui.html
2023-05-02T11:21:32.083+05:30 TRACE 18204 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match request to [Is Secure]
2023-05-02T11:21:32.083+05:30 TRACE 18204 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No HttpSession currently exists
2023-05-02T11:21:32.083+05:30 TRACE 18204 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext : Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
2023-05-02T11:21:32.083+05:30 TRACE 18204 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext : Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
2023-05-02T11:21:32.083+05:30 TRACE 18204 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]
2023-05-02T11:21:32.083+05:30 TRACE 18204 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@60743cdb, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@c02670f, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@2accaec2, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@1da1380b, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@5a1f778, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@654e6a90, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@83bb0f, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@40709f9, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@71179b6f, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@6418e39e, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@5f366587]] (1/1)
2023-05-02T11:21:32.083+05:30 DEBUG 18204 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /error
2023-05-02T11:21:32.083+05:30 TRACE 18204 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/11)
2023-05-02T11:21:32.083+05:30 TRACE 18204 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/11)
2023-05-02T11:21:32.083+05:30 TRACE 18204 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderFilter (3/11)
2023-05-02T11:21:32.083+05:30 TRACE 18204 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/11)
2023-05-02T11:21:32.083+05:30 TRACE 18204 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking CsrfFilter (5/11)
2023-05-02T11:21:32.083+05:30 TRACE 18204 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking LogoutFilter (6/11)
2023-05-02T11:21:32.083+05:30 TRACE 18204 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            : Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
2023-05-02T11:21:32.083+05:30 TRACE 18204 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking RequestCacheAwareFilter (7/11)
2023-05-02T11:21:32.083+05:30 TRACE 18204 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : matchingRequestParameterName is required for getMatchingRequest to lookup a value, but not provided
2023-05-02T11:21:32.083+05:30 TRACE 18204 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (8/11)
2023-05-02T11:21:32.083+05:30 TRACE 18204 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (9/11)
2023-05-02T11:21:32.083+05:30 TRACE 18204 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (10/11)
2023-05-02T11:21:32.083+05:30 TRACE 18204 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AuthorizationFilter (11/11)
2023-05-02T11:21:32.083+05:30 TRACE 18204 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Authorizing SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ FirewalledRequest[ org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@6bd4a761]]
2023-05-02T11:21:32.083+05:30 TRACE 18204 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Checking authorization on SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ FirewalledRequest[ org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@6bd4a761]] using org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizeHttpRequestsConfigurer$$Lambda$701/0x0000000801010c68@5afc8a57
2023-05-02T11:21:32.083+05:30 DEBUG 18204 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /error
2023-05-02T11:21:32.087+05:30 TRACE 18204 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No HttpSession currently exists
2023-05-02T11:21:32.087+05:30 TRACE 18204 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext : Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
2023-05-02T11:21:32.087+05:30 TRACE 18204 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext : Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
2023-05-02T11:21:32.087+05:30 TRACE 18204 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]
```

I am using org.springframework.boot 3.0.6 and jdk 17 versions

Below are my project dependencies.

```
dependencies {
    implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.7.0")
    implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-security:1.7.0")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux")
}
```

And here is SecurityConfig file.

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {
  @Bean
  SecurityFilterChain apiFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize.anyRequest().permitAll()).build();
  }
}
```